# Cannot choose "Run with Performance Tool" -> "OpenGL ES" in Xcode 3

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

In Xcode3, out of all options under "Run" -> "Run with Performance Tool", I can only select:

- Leaks
- CPU Sampler
- Allocations
- Activity monitor

I cannot select any other option including "Zombies", "UI Recorder", etc., or most importantly  for me, "OpenGL ES". I think this is consistent in all iOS projects on the machine, but I did not check.

How can I profile OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the options of Instrument are available only on the Device.
Connect device, change the build from simulator to device... build the app first then try using
instrument and see if your getting what you looking for..

Comment: Fascinating and frightening! That means I'll have to debug GL ES issues on the device itself, apparently from the beginning, instead of debugging on the simulator. I could have sworn I tried this before posting on SO. Thanks!

Comment: But I still can't select most of the options with the device. The only available options are System Usage, Core Animation, Time Profiler, Leaks, CPU Sampler, Allocations, Activity monitor. I want Zombies.

Answer (score 1):

You must first run the project in `Xcode`, then select the `Attach to Process` option in `Instruments` and select your running application. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Instruments solo, it's a regular app and you don't have to launch it from Xcode. Then attach to your process and instrument away...

Comment: I have tried that; I created a new OpenGL ES workspace in Instruments, and attached it to the game process in the simulator. However, the Record button disabled.